# Getting error Object literal may only specify known properties using Wagmi

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm following an example from wagmi using typescript https://wagmi.sh/examples/contract-write  . The code i have is

```
export function Write() {
  const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xFBA3912Ca04dd458c843e2EE08967fC04f3579c2',  //< Error Occurs Here
    abi: [
        {
          name: 'mint',
          type: 'function',
          stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
          inputs: [],
          outputs: [],
        },
      ] as const,
    functionName: 'mint',
  });
  const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);

  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: data?.hash,
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!write || isLoading} onClick={() => write?.()}>
        {isLoading ? 'Minting...' : 'Mint'}
      </button>
      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          Successfully minted your NFT!
          <div>
            <a href={`https://etherscan.io/tx/${data?.hash}`}>Etherscan</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The specific error i am getting is :

```
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'address' does not exist in type 'UsePrepareContractWriteArgs & UsePrepareContractWriteConfig'.ts(2345)
```

I have tried to do put const assertion to the abi but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
const abi = […] as const
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial was for version 0.7.x and i was using 0.6.x, i changed from

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xFBA3912Ca04dd458c843e2EE08967fC04f3579c2',  //< Error Occurs Here
    abi: [
        {
          name: 'mint',
          type: 'function',
          stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
          inputs: [],
          outputs: [],
        },
      ] as const,
    functionName: 'mint',
  });
```

to this and now its working fine

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    addressOrName: "0xFBA3912Ca04dd458c843e2EE08967fC04f3579c2", 
    contractInterface: [
        {
          name: 'mint',
          type: 'function',
          stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
          inputs: [],
          outputs: [],
        },
      ] as const,
    functionName: 'mint',
  });
```